# maven command to compile specific folder from src

Tags: maven, compilation, gatling

I am trying to compile the below set of code from scala folder alone to run my gatling test:
[image]

tried with below command:

```
mvn clean compiler:compile scala:testCompile gatling:test
```

it compiles the entire source code and throws error if anything related to other automation team's code.Due to this my test does not starts. 
 Appreciate if someone had this type of requirement and was able to compile specific set of code.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Since Gatling 3.7 (released 6 months ago), Gatling supports Java. If your main language is Java, why go with Scala for your Gatling tests?

Then, if your Gatling tests don't depend on anything in `src/main/java` nor `src/test/java`, you should probably not have them in the same maven reactor. You have several options, eg:

- move them into an isolated maven project in a subdirectory
- use a [maven profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) dedicated to your Gatling tests where your remap `<sourceDirectory>` and/or `<testSourceDirectory>`